# Are supplements like Glucosamine permanent or temporary?

Tags: medications, inflammation

I've been into body building for the last 25 years, and my joints are in poor shape.

There are things made for sore joints like [Glucosamine Sulfate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UW3E2HW) and [Turmeric Curcumin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DBTFO98) that get great reviews.

But I want to know if these supplements are simply masking the pain or if they are doing anything to repair the damage?

Aspirin, for example, would be temporary and just mask the pain.

I did send this question to the manufacturers, but they said they did not have any data.

Comment: If you think your joints are affecting your life seriously, you may consider to get them checked for osteoarthritis and other joint problems to see if the pain actually arises from the joints or nearby structures, such as ligaments or muscle tendons.

Comment: @Jan, I usually get annual checkups. The last few years that I have been reporting this, my doctor said that's what happens when I lead an active lifestyle. Maybe I need another doctor. Does that mean you don't know if these supplements are permanent or temporary?

Comment: If your joints are in "poor shape," any heavy physical activity can make them worse. So, the first thing to try can be to stop such activities for a period of time and see if the pain decreases. Otherwise, glucosamine would just mask the problem, even if it can have some protective effect. This google search _site:gov glucosamine cartilage "systematic review"_ shows some studies about glucosamine effects on joint cartilage. The effect depend on the presence/absence of the osteoarthritis. Some imaging investigation (X ray...) would be needed for a diagnosis of osteoarthritis.